# How do I set cookies for individual pages for use with colorbox?

Tags: cookies, load, colorbox

I have been using a script with colorbox that writes a cookie when a page is visited and only opens the colorbox on page load if the page has not been visited in the last month.

I would now like to amend this so that it writes and checks for a cookie for the specific page rather than the domain as a whole.  This is because I am publishing a new page each month and would like a colorbox to open the first time a user visits the new page each month.  Here is the script as it currently stands:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') === -1) {
                   var expires = new Date();
                   expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+31);
                   document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();

               $.colorbox({href:'welcome.html', width:"60%", speed:1500});
               }
```

Could someone help me adapt this to work on a page-by-page basis,

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this:

I changed this line:

```
document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();
```

to this:

```
document.cookie = "visited=true; path=/page.php; expires="+expires.toUTCString();
```